# Podio Upload File Error

Tags: php, json, podio

I am using the **PHP Podio** library.

I am using the upload function but I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PodioBadRequestError: "Invalid JSON" Request URL: http://api.podio.com/file/v2/
```

**Can anyone can help please?**

Comment: Can you share your json? (Error is pretty specific `invalid json`)

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio The data was correct but I think the library files had some issues. I downloaded PHP library again and my issue resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty self evident: the data in your request isn't formatted correctly.